# Prolog Recursion | using multiple predicates to calculate sum

Tags: prolog

could someone tell me how do I solve the below question:

***people_in_capitals(N): N is the total number of people living in capital cities of the world.***

**"*Useful predicates:***

***country(Name, ID, Capital, CapitalProvince, Size, Population)***

***city(Name, Country ID, Province, Population, Lat, Lon, Elevation)."***

I can use "findall" function to get and store the capitals in List, however, how do I use items in the list to find the population from the predicate city?

Answer (score 0):

Show your code so far!

Also, write a predicate that iterates over the list (as described here: https://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/lists.html) and sums the city population into the target value.